# Automatic re-reading of the source file with shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, batch-processing, shinyapps

I have an application, where I need to update the source data periodically. Source datafile is a csv file normally stored in the project directory and read with read.csv. The csv. file is changed every day with the updates. The name of the file does not change...just few cases are added.

I need the application to re-read the source pdf file with some periodicity (e.g. once per day). I can do it with **reactiveFileReader** function and it works when I am running the application from Rstudio, but not after I deploy the application on the web with shinyapps.io.

Can this be even done, when I am not using my own server but shinyapps.io?

Comment: Interesting question. What if you store the csv on some page like github? Can't you simply add an action button to reload the data?

Comment: Since this board is more coding oriented, I suggest you share the code with some minimal example data. This way people can check if the solution lies elsewhere